# why exec('print(x)') is executed while print(x) goes wrong in this python code?

Tags: python, printing, syntax, local-variables

```
def build(s, loc):
    exec(s, loc)
    return loc

def main():
    L = build('x = 1', locals())
    locals().update(L)
    exec('print(x)')

  
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

When I run the code above, the python console will show '1'.

```
def build(s, loc):
    exec(s, loc)
    return loc

def main():
    L = build('x = 1', locals())
    locals().update(L)
    print(x)
  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

When I run the code above, it will show 'name 'x' is not defined'.

What is the difference between them?

I modified my code for reducing ambiguity, a similar problem persists.

```
def main():
    exec('x = 1')
    exec('print(x)')
    
  
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

This will show '1'.

```
def main():
    exec('x = 1')
    print(x)
    
  
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

This will go wrong.

Comment: Modifying `locals` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I add more details, the similar error still exists.

Comment: Modifying local variables with `exec` is also undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm assuming it could be the interpreter not understanding that `exec('x = 1')` instantiated a new variable `x`, and so mistakenly assuming your second code contains a syntax error when proofreading it before execution - while it should run fine, and so passes the syntax check just fine in your first example when x is called through an `exec` call

Answer (score -1):

This is related to ***scope***.

When doing this:

```py
def main():
    exec('x = 1')
    print(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

The x variable defined by exec, which is local, is not the same x variable as the one passed to the print() function, which is global. Unless you tell it to be:

```py
def main():
    exec('global x;x = 1')
    print(x)
    
  
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

This ended up working for me, it prints 1.

This is because after using the `global` keyword on the x variable in exec(), you're telling the interpreter that despite being in a local scope, any further references to the x variable will reference the outer, **global**, x variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if i modify main() function as: def main():x =1;print(locals()['x']);print(x), it prints '1/n1'. It means x is still a local variable even x is defined by x = 1. And if modify main() as: def main():x=1;print(globals()['x'];print(x)), the KeyError will be occurred.